# Get JTable to print tabular format

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, format

So I have a standard JTable and I want the user to be able to print it out.  I used JTable.print() and that's fine for printing out an exact replica of the table, but I was hoping to have it more in a tabular format, with just the column names and then the data beneath them, no grids or anything.  I thought this would be simple, but I have no clue what to do!  Has anybody done this?  If so, can someone provide me with code sample/example?  Thank you.

Comment: This is not really a "provide me with the code" type of site. If you're having problems doing this, why not show us your attempt and describe any problems you might be having with your code.

Comment: Have you tried setting the tables grid lines as invisible?

Comment: If you know basic HTML, you can build an HTML document consisting of only a <table>, place that document in a JEditorPane, and call that JEditorPane's print method (inherited from JTextComponent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable the grid lines, for example...

```
JTable printTable = new JTable(table.getModel());
printTable.setSize(printTable.getPreferredSize());
JTableHeader tableHeader = printTable.getTableHeader();
tableHeader.setSize(tableHeader.getPreferredSize());

printTable.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
printTable.setShowVerticalLines(false);
printTable.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH);
```

This uses a temporary, offscreen `JTable` to do the actually printing, so you will need to be sure to configure any required renderers, but the idea is sound.

This basic ensures that the `JTable` that is on the screen doesn't get updated with the changed, which could be kind of freaking to users.

It also allows you to change the `TableHeader` should you want to to ;)

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer .  This works, except when I print it, there is still a border around the whole table.  So no gridlines, but still lines around the entirety of the border.  I've tried using table.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()); but that didn't work.  Any ideas??

Comment: And to clarify, when I say print, I mean like printing it out of a printer.  Not just printing the table to the screen.

Comment: Yes, the intention o fthis code is to print it to the printer. You could try setting the tables border to a EmpryBorder