# How to print multiple Jframe if item in table is greater then the table can hold without scrollpane

Tags: java, swing, printing, jframe

hey a very good day to all of the people on stackoverflow.

I am currently making a POS for a restaurant and I have completed everything. Now its come down to the printing process and I have done the coding which is working perfectly. Here's the coding for printing

```
jTable100.setModel(jTable1.getModel());
    try {
        String printerNameDesired = "Microsoft Print to PDF";

        PrintService[] service = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices(); // list of printers
        DocPrintJob docPrintJob = null;
        int count = service.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (service[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(printerNameDesired)) {
                docPrintJob = service[i].createPrintJob();
                i = count;
            }
        }
        PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        pjob.setPrintable(this);
        pjob.setPrintService(docPrintJob.getPrintService());
        pjob.setJobName("job");
        pjob.print();
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DineInPrintDialogBox.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The output is [PrintOut Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA5CW.png)

Now there's a problem that as you can see in the picture that the table is scrollable and not able to print all the details. so I want is that whenever the table has more then 5 item, like for example 12, I want that it may print the first 5 on the first page, then on the second page and 2 on the last page.

how can I achieve this?

and my second problem is how can I adjust the size of the jframe according to the printer page size. like how can the printer tell the java program that the page size is whatever it supports. for example the printer supports a1 size. How can the printer tell the program that the size of the page is a1 and it should properly fit.

Thanks in advance and hope things are fine with everyone on StackOverflow.

Comment: JTable has printing capabilities of its own, I suggest reading the JavaDocs

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544013/how-to-print-a-jtable-object-in-the-java-application/14544898#14544898) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294117/get-jtable-to-print-tabular-format/24297085#24297085)

Comment: I'd also highly recommend having a look at a good reporting engine, like Jasper Reports

Comment: ok so can I add image to the header?

Comment: and how can I add more text like when the table reaches it last row, I want to print total amount under it?

Comment: I really wish you hadn't asked that, but here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it/34114959#34114959)

Comment: Thanks and can i add a logo to the header and center it up?

Comment: Yes, see the linked example in my previous comment

Comment: can u just post a answer so I can mark it and close this question?